# C# использование класса из DLL как наследника класса программы

Tags: c#, наследование, dll, интерфейс, рефлексия

Суть задачи такая:

Есть программа, которая имеет класс `Item`, и есть условный класс `Cucumber`, наследуемый от `Item`. Так же в программе есть множество интерфейсов, отвечающие за специфичные особенности предметов. Так, тот же `Cucumber` имеет интерфейс `IFresh`, чтобы тот имел свойства и методы, описывающие его свежесть и возможность испортиться.

И главное: каким образом можно реализовать добавление новых предметов из DLL (динамически), учитывая что они наследуются от `Item` и могут иметь интерфейсы? Пусть это будет условный `Tomato` с тем же `IFresh`.

PS: Это только вариант, возможно есть более оптимальный способ добавления новых предметов, не относящийся к DLL и рефлексии. Буду благодарен за альтернативные варианты.

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы делаете плагинную систему. Стандартный способ делать это - [MEF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/).

Comment: [Здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/449a6e3f-74ac-4239-adde-a41d2ef63365/10571086107910761072108510801077?forum=fordesktopru) пример, как вручную грузить плагины на основе интерфейса.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, большое спасибо! Использование отдельного dll как SDK для проекта и дополнения к проекту, странно что не находил такое очевидное решение. Изучил, разобрался, и успешно реализовал. Только `Item` использовал не как интерфейс, а как абстрактный класс, более логично в моем случае.